# Android Testing: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

Tags: android, unit-testing, instrumentation

I have 3 test classes for a particular package from my main application. My first test class is running just fine, the other 2 aren't.

When I try to run those 2 tests, I get the following error:

```
Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'
```

I already verified:

- if the build path was properly configured,
- if the target package is correct,
- if I had problems with importing jUnit.

Any guess about what the problem is?

-----//-----

**Solution:**

I changed the version of jUnit I was using and the tests perform as they should.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add JUnit library to your package as following:

On Eclipse, right click on your test project, choose Properties --> Java Build Path, on Order and Export tab, please check on JUnit 4 and click OK.

After that, clean or rebuild your test project and run.

Answer (score 1):

Java build path should export JUnit 4 library(checked) and Ensure you clean and rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

have you define your other two class in "AndroidManifest"

Comment: In my target project or in my test project? The target already has those classes in its Manifest.